# JS: function not defined, Unable to create JSON object because JS not able to recognize the key is string

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have JS script function that holds cart items to order food.
This function is passed with 2 parameters ID and price.

My script file looks like

```
 <script>
    function addtocart(mitem, mprice) {
            var price = String(mprice)
            var mobj = { String(mitem): price }

            var storeobj = JSON.stringify(mobj)
            localStorage.setItem('cart', storeobj)
        }

    </script>
```

My button looks like this

```
 <p style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px"><button class="button" style="width: 200px" onclick="addtocart( '{{M.Menu_Item}}', '{{M.Menu_ItemPrice}}' )" >Add to Cart</button>
```

When I click on the button in developer console in chrome says that addtocart function not defined.

I did read about on click listens but I have to pass the parameter for each button click, which is different. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are both in the same file? As your question is in django... I must ask, are you doing this directly in the html template of your django project? When you go to the website and inspect the page code, do you see your javascript script there? Is it possible that django is removing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [ ] to set mobj.

```
var mobj = { [String(mitem)]: price };
```

Basically, Chrome is throwing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" at

```
var mobj = { String(mitem): price }
```

which means it is not recognizing your JS code due to syntax error.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it.